# WPF UserControl Style -- How do I set the style from the parent if the control is in an external assembly?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources, styles

Basically I have the following structure:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.company.com/WPF/Controls"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType={x:Type TextBlock}>
            ...
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <my:MyUserControl1 />
        <my:MyUserControl1 />
        <my:MyUserControl2 />
        <my:MyUserControl2 />
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl ...
             >
    <TextBlock Style={ ?? What Goes Here ??} />
</UserControl>
```

---

How do I apply the style declared in the Window resources so that it goes to the UserControl that is being pulled from an external assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the Style to be applied to all `TextBlock`s, including the ones in `MyUserControl`, just leave the x:Key out and it will be applied implictly

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

---

If you want it to be set explicitly you can use `DynamicResource` in the `UserControl`s

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <my:UserControl1 />
    <my:UserControl1 />
    <my:UserControl1 />
    <my:UserControl1 />
</StackPanel>

<UserControl ...>
    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle1}" Text="TextBlock"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: @Aaron: If you use a `StaticResource` you'll get an Exception saying "Cannot find resource named 'MyStyle1'. Resource names are case sensitive"

Comment: Right...noticed the resource is in a Window; not App.xaml or other merged in ResourceDictionary. OP should yank it out of Window...

Comment: @Aaron: I thought the same thing at first but there might be scenarios where this is useful. For example, two different Windows can Style the same UserControl in different ways. Not that I can come up with a scenario where I would need that but still..

Comment: True; but as you said...use case is hard to come by

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<TextBlock Style={ StaticResource MyStyle1} />
```

I hope this help you [Introduction to Styles in WPF](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Styles.html)